# Getting value of ng-change field in my angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-change, angularjs-templates

I have this line in my view:

```
<input placeholder="Search" type="text" ng-change="searchChange()" ng-model="mySearch" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">
```

And then inside my controller I have:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('listViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $http) {

    $http.get('http://www.domain.co.uk/api/search.php').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.food = response.data;
        });

    $scope.searchChange = function() {
        console.log($scope.mySearch);   
    };         

}])
```

But this is giving me "undefined".

How can I reference the value of the mySearch input field in my controller?

Comment: I think it's because in Javascript function, your scope changes. Here is the documentation about scopes : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp.

When you call $scope.mySearch into your function, it is searching for local variable mySearch into the function, which doesn't exist

Comment: Does it always give you `undefined`? After typing anything in that input

Comment: @taguenizy correct - whatever I input gives me "undefined"

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the controller? @Chris

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bsqkv75r/2/ , your code seems to work fine...

Comment: Thanks all - I have updated my code above

Comment: @Alburkerk, this is not true.. function in javaScript can use variables from outer scopes, but not the other way around. `ng-change` scope is not isolated so `$scope.mySearch` should be available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your input field might be located within a sperate scope, which is not updated correctly. `ngIf` and `ng-repeat` are common examples for directives creating a separate sub-scope. (See [this article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for more information around scopes)

### Dotted scope variables

To protect yourself from such issues you might either store your variables inside objects.

```
<input placeholder="Search" type="text" ng-change="searchChange()" ng-model="my.search" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">


$scope.my = {search: ""};
$scope.searchChange = function() {  
    console.log($scope.my.search);
};
```

### Named Controllers

Or name your controllers specifically as recommended in the angular style guide [Y030](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y030).

### Pass variable as parameter

A third option is simply passing the variable as parameter to the function:

```
<input placeholder="Search" type="text" ng-change="searchChange(mySearch)" ng-model="mySearch" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">



$scope.searchChange = function(mySearch) {  
    console.log(mySearch);
};
```

Comment: Your third option worked immediately. Let me use this for now and then read about options one and two later. Thank you.

Comment: Great answer!
From what I read, `ng-change` does not create an isolated scope (as `ng-if` does for example..), so how can we explain why wasn't `$scope.mySearch` available in the first place?

Comment: You are right, `ngChange` does not create a new scope. Maybe the input field was just wrapped by a `ngIf`?