# Undefined parameter in controller from ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got data from API, which I use to display a form. Form contains cascading select fields. I've got 2 functions to filter my array with results for the next select, but I can't read property from ng-model.

For example I choose first option and get it's ID, then I need to pass that ID to my function in controller, which can filter an array to return proper options.

API DATA

```
section: { id: "111", name: "Section1" }
nomination: { id: "666", name: "Nomination2" }
category: { id: "999", name: "Category2"}
```

SERVICE

```
const allSections = [
    { id: '111', section: 'Section1' },
    { id: '222', section: 'Section2' },
    { id: '333', section: 'Section3' },
];
const allNominations = [
    { id: '555', sectionId: '111', nomination: 'Nomination1' },
    { id: '666', sectionId: '222', nomination: 'Nomination2' },
    { id: '777', sectionId: '333', nomination: 'Nomination3' },
];
const allCategories = [
   { id: '999', sectionId: '111', category: 'Category1' },
   { id: '888', sectionId: '222', category: 'Category2' },
   { id: '000', sectionId: '333', category: 'Category3' },
];
getSection() {
   return allSections;
},
getSectionNomination(sectionId) {
   const nominations = ($filter('filter')(allNominations, { sectionId }));
   return nominations;
},
getNominationCategory(sectionId) {
   const categories = ($filter('filter')(allCategories, { sectionId }));
   return categories;
},
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.award = {};
$scope.sections = awards_service.getSection();
$scope.getSectionNominations = () => {
    $scope.nominations = 
    awards_service.getSectionNomination($scope.award.section.id);
    $scope.categories = [];
};
$scope.getNominationCategories = () => {
    $scope.categories = 
    awards_service.getNominationCategory($scope.award.section.id);
};
```

VIEW

```
<select ng-model="award.section.id"
        ng-change="getSectionNominations()" 
        ng-options="object.id as object.section for object in sections")
</select>

<select ng-model="award.nomination.id"
        ng-change="getNominationCategories()"
        ng-options="object.id as object.section for object in nominations") 
</select>

<select ng-model="award.category.id"
        ng-options="object.id as object.section for object in categories"
</select>
```

I try to get selected ID from API Data and filter my arrays. In view I can see the proper ID as award.section.id, but when I pass this papameter to function in my controller I get undefined result. 
$scope.award.section.id is underfined.

Comment: try to define object in award scope: `$scope.award = {section: {id: ''}};`

Comment: @num8er I've tried that already, no result

Comment: You've a typo in selects see `sections")` must be `sections">`

Comment: @num8er my bad, I've get it from my jade file and made a mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass current value of select to function:

```
$scope.sectionId = 0;
if ($scope.sections && $scope.sections[0]) {
  $scope.sectionId = $scope.sections[0].id;
}
$scope.getSectionNominations = (sectionId) => {
    if (!sectionId) return;

    $scope.nominations = awards_service.getSectionNomination(sectionId);
    $scope.categories = [];
};
```

and in html:

```
<select 
  ng-model="sectionId"
  ng-change="getSectionNominations(sectionId)" 
  ng-options="object.id as object.section for object in sections"
>
</select>
```

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616573/getting-value-of-ng-change-field-in-my-angularjs-controller) in **Pass variable as parameter**

Comment: great solution! thanks! Could you help me to initialize "sectionId" value on page load, cause when the view loaded, select fields have there values from api, but when I try to choose some value, filter isn't working, but when I click on select and choose some option, then sectionId are getting initialize and filter start to work

Comment: @OlegShchegolev what You want to be as initial value for sectionId? the first one from sections?

Comment: yeah, that's nice, but if I have sectionId value from API? Now I get this: I get sectionId from API and can see it in my view {{award,section.id}}, but in controller console.log(sectionId) return underfined, BUT the select have selected option on load! Then when I choose something in select field, console.log immediately return sectionId value.

Comment: yeap, the first one from section

Comment: @OlegShchegolev try now. keep  in mind if it will be http api result it must be done different.

Comment: still can't understand why sectionId on load is underfined even is API data isn't empty

Comment: @OlegShchegolev is it http call or getting data from hardcoded array? if it's http call so it should be initialized differently.

Comment: it's a http call, could you suggest how to init it in that way?

Comment: @OlegShchegolev please add to Your question how You call, then I’ll give proper answer. Cause I don't know how You do request. (using `axios, fetch, $http` or what?)